# Uploading to App Store from Xcode's Archice doesn't take the provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I'm using `Xcode 7.0.1` and I just had to reactivate the provisioning profile for distributing the app because it expired. It is now active again, and correctly set in my target's Build settings > Code signing identity, but when I archive the app and I try to upload it, Xcode doesn't select such provisioning profile, it takes one by default (XC:...).

Has somebody else experienced this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Removing the provisioning that Xcode created (XC:...), it takes again mine.